# How can I get python keywords in c#

Tags: c#, python

I'm generating `Python` script with `c#`. But I have to know if word is keyword. The question : is there any library for c# which i can get the python keywords ?

Comment: just create a list of python keywords and build a hashset (or something equivalent). It's not like they change often...

Comment: When the script does not require to be human readable, just make any name end with an underscore and they won't clash with any keyword.

Comment: Actually I want to know "is there a library for this ?"

Comment: maybe you could try to describe your problem more... do you have examples? Actually your question is not very understandable .-(

Comment: I'm looking for a library like **Microsoft.Scripting** which including python keywors.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Roll your own.

Comment: Roll your own by referring to the Python function iskeyword() in the standard library in keyword.py and translate this to c#. Also 'as' and 'None' may or may not be in this list but should be included for future compatibility (http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/ref/keywords.html)

Comment: @leancz That is a *very* old version of python to be referencing. `as` and `None` are keywords and have been for several years (since 2.6 IIRC).  See http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords for an up-to-date list.